# Can not install Mangento

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install magento 2.3.4:

```
bin/magento setup:install \
      --no-interaction \
      --backend-frontname admin \
      --db-host mysql \
      --db-name mage2 \
      --db-user root \
      --db-password secret \
      --admin-firstname John \
      --admin-lastname Doe \
      --admin-email admin@localhost.com \
      --admin-user admin \
      --admin-password adminadmin123 \
      --base-url "http://127.0.0.1:8000" \
      --use-secure 0 \
      --use-secure-admin 0 \
      --timezone Asia/Tokyo \
      --use-rewrites 1 \
      --session-save redis \
      --session-save-redis-host redis \
      --session-save-redis-db 4 \
      --cache-backend=redis \
      --cache-backend-redis-server redis \
      --cache-backend-redis-db 5 \
      --page-cache=redis \
      --page-cache-redis-server redis \
      --page-cache-redis-db 6 \
      --use-sample-data
```

My composer.json file is:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "7.3.*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.14.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "~3.0.0",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "2.4.5",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.4.0",
        "tddwizard/magento2-fixtures": "^0.9.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "version": "2.3.2",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

I had run the `setup:di:compile` previously. When I run the installation command above, I get the following error:

```
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...
[Progress: 1 / 1313]
Required extensions check...
[Progress: 2 / 1313]
Enabling Maintenance Mode...

In Mysql.php line 110:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mage2.core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data` AS `main
  _table`


In Mysql.php line 91:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mage2.core_config_data' doesn't exist
```

I commented out all plugins in the `config.php` file and removed the `app/code` directory but it didn't help. The database exists and empty.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I didn't know that the `app/etc/env.php` should be removed if there were previous installations in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty explicit, the installation fails because your table core_config_data is missing.

Now, I can't really say why you don't have it.

My guess is that you commented your `config.php` (which list all actived modules). So probably the installer that should create the core_config_data table is not running.

This is what this table should looks like, the maintenance flag is inside that table and that's why you have the error, he can't access the table to set the maintenance flag

[image: table core config data]

It's also the table that contains everything magento needs such as path.

Also you may want to check your `env.php` to check if the database you are going to is the good one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I found that in my case the issue was in the `env.php` file presence. When I removed it, the setup process has finished successfully.